# How to store more than 8000 characters and assign large concatenated string in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to concatenate the large number of id'd and to update the status of all id's.

For example:

```
aclid in (4604019,4604018,4604017,4604016,4604015,4604014,4604013,4604012,4604011,4604010,4604009,4604008,4604007,4604006,4604005,4604004,4604003,4604002,4604001,4604000,4603999,4603998,4603997,4603996,4603995,4603994,4603993,4603992,4603991,4603990,4603989,4603988)`
```

Please check my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VT_ACLReportChangeStatus]
    (@ChangeStatus nvarchar(50) = null,
     @ACLId nvarchar(max))
AS
    /* Exec VT_ACLReportChangeStatus 'Complete','4599473,4599472,4599471,4599469,4599468' */
BEGIN 
    UPDATE VT_ACLReport 
    SET Status = @ChangeStatus 
    WHERE ACLId IN (SELECT * FROM SplitDelimiterString(@ACLId,','))
END
```

Please check my code behind:

```
ACLId = ACLId.ToString().Trim(',');

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("VT_ACLReportChangeStatus", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACLId", SqlDbType.NVarChar,-1));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangeStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@ACLId"].Value = ACLId;
    cmd.Parameters["@ChangeStatus"].Value = ddlChangeStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

`AclId` column data type is `bigint identity`.

Please can you help me in concatenating large string and to update all rows whose aclid is present.

Comment: In the immediate, your issue is most likely with how your string split function is working.  In a more broad sense however, your issue is that you are concatenating all your IDs together in the first place?  Why are you doing this and not just holding them in a table that you can join to?

Comment: According to my requirement , i have to update the status of selected id's in the same table . so i concatenated all selected id's and then trying to update the rows in one go. but problem is coming if the more then 8000 character, it's not taking more than 8000 character in stored procedure.

Comment: *so i concatenated all selected id's* .... why?  There is no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, create one user defined table type in sql and one class in sourecode with your respective data. You can pass object of this class to sql and in your SP you can use join between main table and this table(which is received as input parameter) to update data.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your answers..

Actually it was silly mistake,while calling splitting function in Stored procedure. In function it was varchar(8000).

:) solved it..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for your answers.. Actually it was silly mistake,while calling splitting function in Stored procedure. In function it was varchar(8000). :) solved it.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitDelimiterString] (@StringWithDelimiter VARCHAR(max), @Delimiter VARCHAR(max))
RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartingPosition INT;
    DECLARE @ItemInString VARCHAR(max);
    SELECT @StartingPosition = 1;
    --Return if string is null or empty
    IF LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) = 0 OR @StringWithDelimiter IS NULL RETURN; 
    WHILE @StartingPosition > 0
    BEGIN
        --Get starting index of delimiter .. If string
        --doesn't contain any delimiter than it will returl 0 
        SET @StartingPosition = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@StringWithDelimiter); 

        --Get item from string        
        IF @StartingPosition > 0                
            SET @ItemInString = SUBSTRING(@StringWithDelimiter,0,@StartingPosition)
        ELSE
            SET @ItemInString = @StringWithDelimiter;
        --If item isn't empty than add to return table    
        IF( LEN(@ItemInString) > 0)
            INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) VALUES (@ItemInString);            

        --Remove inserted item from string
        SET @StringWithDelimiter = SUBSTRING(@StringWithDelimiter,@StartingPosition + 
                     LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) - @StartingPosition)

        --Break loop if string is empty
        IF LEN(@StringWithDelimiter) = 0 BREAK;
    END

    RETURN
END
```